# PHP replace all instances with single regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a single regex and I want to replace each match in the array of matches with a corresponding array of replacements in the most efficient way possible.

So for instance, I have:

```
$string = '~~hello~~ there, how ~~are~~ ~~you~~?';

$pattern = '/~~(.*?)~~/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'hi';
$replacements[1] = 'am';
$replacements[2] = 'i';
```

and I want to turn `$string` into:

```
hi there, how am i?
```

Initially I hoped it'd be as simple as:

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $string);
```

but it doesn't seem to work. So the first question is: if `$replacements` is an array, then does `$string` must also be an array?

Now, I can come up with (seemingly) inefficient ways to do this, like counting the number of matches and making an array filled with the appropriate number of identical regexes. But this leads us into question two: is there a more efficient way? How would you do it, PHP pros?

Comment: Are you always replacing the matches with the same text based on the order they matched? (eg, would `'~~are~~ there, how ~~are~~ ~~you~~?'` become `'am there, how am i?'` or would it still become `'hello there, how am i?'`?

Comment: While I may eventually do something fancy like the former, for now I'm just looking for the latter. To be explicit: `'~~are~~ there, how ~~are~~ ~~you~~?'` would still become `'hi there, how am i?'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple eval trick here:

```
print preg_replace('/~~(\w+)~~/e', 'array_shift($replacements)', $st);
```

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) will simply fetch the first entry from your replacement array.

Better would be using a map though (`"hello" => "hi"`).

Comment: hmm...@mario, I got `hi there, how hi hi?` when I tried this. I can imagine it working if I ran it through a loop, but then it'd be performing the search multiple times. Is that what you're suggesting I do?

Comment: Oh I've got it working now...I must have made a typo. Nice answer, dude! I'll go ahead and accept it, but if you've got time, do you think you could explain what each change you've made is doing in a bit more depth? I'd really appreciate it. Also, with the map, do you mean utilizing the `array_map` function?

Comment: It's just the `/e` eval modifier. This allows to call a function instead of just using a replacement pattern. Basically a shortened `preg_replace_callback`. -- With map I meant a `'$map["$1"]'` as second paramenter, prefilled like `$map = array("hello"=>"hi", "are"=>"am")`

Answer (score 1):

I might use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$string = '~~hello~~ there, how ~~are~~ ~~you~~?';

$pattern = '/~~(.*?)~~/'; 

var_dump(preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
    function($matches) { 
        static $replacements = array('hi', 'am', 'i'), $i = 0; 
        return $replacements[$i++ % count($replacements)]; 
    }, 
    $string));
```

Output:

```
string(19) "hi there, how am i?"
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is switch out those three specific phrases with another set of specific phrases, then you can just use `str_replace` as it is much faster than `preg_replace`.

```
$subject = "~~hello~~ there, how ~~are~~ ~~you~~?";
$matches = array('~~hello~~', '~~are~~', '~~you~~');
$replace = array('hi', 'am', 'i');

str_replace($matches, $replace, $subject);
```

Comment: Nice answer, Choy. I'm going to look into this to see if it's something that will work for my particular situation.